# CPU running at low speed

Tags: windows-7, cpu, cpu-speed, clockspeed, windows-experience-index

I'm using Dell Inspiron 15R N5110, which has Intel Core I7 2630QM.  I recently installed Windows 7 SP1, uninstalling Windows 10. I ran Windows Experience Index and CPU-Z:

[image: Windows Experience Index]

[image: CPU-Z]

and my CPU rating is decreased to 4.5 (previously 7 or above). I checked CPU-Z showing the CPU running at a low speed.At task manager resource monitor in windows 8.1 it show CPU speed always at 0.76 GHz remains same even if I load CPU heavily up to 100% .

But I also checked in Safe Mode there CPU stuck at 2.0 GHz always.I can't figure out what is going on.

Comment: Low speed? It's running at its base frequency. Windows experience index is notorious for its poor rating, giving low rating even for some top of the line hardware. Try running a CPU intensive application and see if it goes to its turbo frequency of 2.9 GHz. If it does, then everything is fine.

Comment: well I heavily loaded CPU to 100% usage but still running at same speed 798.10 MHz and not going to to turbo frequency. And also a month ago I tested my pc via Dell pre boot assessment ePSA and my CPU fan was failed in it but seems to work fine.
Is can be problem with fan or speed is another issue.

Comment: And also I check CPU-Z at another CPU Toshiba Satellite P55W-C, Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5200U 2.20GHz and that was running at 2495.94 GHz and varies between 789.10 MHz to 2495.94 GHz turbo speed but my CPU seems to be running at same speeds above displayed by CPU-z constantly.and not even Multiplier and bus speed changes. And also during bench CPU test my system slows down whereas other CPU mentioned don't slow down.

Comment: so what can be the problem??? overheating??? or CPU frequency decreased??? or is it possible??? how to increase it? Or it is just normal???

Comment: change power plan to balanced or high performance and not power saving

Comment: Power plan is balanced already.

Comment: Have you installed all the Intel drivers listed for your laptop? Dell's website will have them.

Comment: Yes I did installed all the softwares.

Comment: Is it because of or related to cooling system or  processor fan?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Experience Index is a really bad way to judge your hardware (this precisely being the reason why it was subsequently removed by Microsoft). To really judge your hardware, you must rely only on two things:

1) Proper benchmarks (e.g. PCMark, PassMark, 3DMark, Unigine Heaven etc.)

2) Experience. Whether you really feel your PC has slowed down. This can again be dangerous due to the opposite of the placebo effect.

Comment: yup I know but CPU-Z is showing  my CPU is running constantly on Base speed 798.10 MHz and it's the maximam speed at which CPU works. but I checked at different CPU where CPU-Z shows the speed varies from 2495.94 GHz to 798.10 MHz but my My laptop CPU is only running at 798.10 MHz but marginally decreases and doesn't get turbo frequency.

Comment: And my PC to work fine but sometimes it slows down and stucks after seconds.

Comment: How the CPU functions isn't really controlled much by software, except the power plan. Set the plan to high performance and instead of applications like CPU-z, simply use task manager to monitor clock speed.

Comment: Well at task manager resource monitor in windows 8.1 it show speed always at 0.76 GHz remains same even if I load CPU heavily.

But I also checked in Safe Mode it Worked fine there and CPU speed goes above 0.76GHz and even to Turbo as well. But I can't figure out what is the problem in Normal Mode.

Comment: Did you check the power plan

Comment: Yes I did check which was default for both max and min processor stats.
and also at safe mode CPU stuck at 2.0 GHz always and doesn't varies speed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone finally I found what was the problem and it is sorted. Actually My laptop fan had problem. One of his wire was unplugged  probably which controls the CPU fan and power cable was fine and that's why CPU usage was always reduced to 39% and maximum speed was 0.78 GHz and now CPU works fine goes to full speed as well as above full speed trough Turbo. And CPU rating in windows experience improved as well to 7.4.
Thanks again :).